# How to insert, update, delete in struts using only one action class and without using dispatch action or lookupdispatch action?

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2

How can I write a program to insert, update, delete in struts using only one action class and without using dispatch action or lookupdispatch action? Is it possible to do so?

Comment: without using dispatch action or lookupdispatch action? can you clarify this?

Comment: You seem to be using `struts1`. Why can't you switch to `struts2`? You can't do that in `struts1` without using `DispatchAction`.

Comment: Why would you want to? That's their purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There is a action you wrote:

```
class ProductAction extends ActionSupport{
    public String insert(){...}
    public String update(){...}
    public String delete(){...}
    public String view(){...}
}
```

There are two ways to achieve your goal.

First, **dynamic method invocation** inherited from webwork.It is a embedded feature, you needn't do anything. A reference to "**http://baseurl/product!insert.action**" points to ProductAction and calls its insert method instead of execute method.  It uses "!" to declare the method to be called.

The second is using **Wildcard Method**.
You configure your action as bellow:

```
<action name="product_*" class="actionpackage.ProductAction" method="{1}">
```

A reference to "**product_insert.action**" will call the insert method.

Comment: Ok fine..plz tell me more about that ActionSupport class and also where I need to write my execute or it is not required?

Comment: This answer is for struts 2, not struts 1.

Comment: Also, those action methods in your example should return strings, not void.

Comment: Yes, it is for struts2. I have never used struts1. To user1578217: If you use struts1, I am not able to help you, sorry for this. To  Steven Benitez: thanks, I have amended.